# How to setup AI only game, ala "Battle Royale"?

Tags: civilization-6

I wish to setup an AI only game like they have done recently when Firaxis streamed a live game.

I have not tried and have uninstalled Civ5, but apparently it has this ability.

Is there a way to do this currently with Civ6? I have no doubt that if not, it will soon.

Bored computer wants something to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a mod available.
https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/autoplay.25735/

The mod allows you to see all units across the whole map. Including resources where they will eventually be discovered once the AI researches the tech.

A useful option is that at any point, you can set that all AI Civs have to declare war with each other.

Another use for this auto play mod is to help developers of mods test their own mods.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is not yet a way to set up an AI only game for CIV VI. CIV V had the IGE mod, where you could basically delete your units and watch the AI battle it out, but Civ VI does not have this as of yet.